# Django - How can this UpdateView return to a filtered TableView?

Tags: django

I have a Django project in which I have a TableView with filters on it. It can redirect to UpdateViews and DeleteViews from the rows in the table, and it works fine, and the UpdateView correctly redirects to the TableView on success.

My issue is, I can't manage to make the UpdateView redirected to the TableView while keeping the filters the TableView had when the UpdateView was called.

The UpdateView has this `get_context_data` method, in which I'm able to send the filtered URL:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SaleUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...
        context['referrer'] = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        return context
```

I made a button in the HTML template to redirect to that referrer, which should redirect to the filtered TableView, but it redirects me to the unfiltered TableView. I think it has to do with my `form_valid` method and `get_success_url` method:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


    def get_success_url(self, form):
        ...
        return reverse_lazy('sale_list')
```

How can I access either the `self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` or the `referer` data I sent to the template, in the context of the `get_success_url` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine there must be better ways to solve this, but I solved the issue by doing the following:

***1.*** Sending the `referer` to the UpdateView's template like this:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SaleDeleteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['referrer'] = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        return context
```

***2.*** Adding it to the template's `<form>` in a hidden input like this:

```
<input name="referrer" id="id_referrer" type="hidden" value="{{ referrer }}">
```

***3.*** Retrieving it in the `get_success_url` method in my UpdateView

```
    def get_success_url(self):
        referrer = self.request.POST['referrer']
        if str(referrer) not in ['', 'None']:
            return referrer
        return reverse_lazy('sale_list')
```

I added that last validation in case the user reloads the UpdateView, in which case the `referer` would be empty.